'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
I'm working on some code to encrypt a word into numbers from the polybius square, however I need the output to be the two numbers right next to each other e.g. 41 instead of a coordinate format (4, 1). Item.replace hasn't been working to get rid of the unnecessary characters, as it returns 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. How can i get the output that i want?
import numpy as np
polybius_square = np.array([["a","b","c","d","e"],
                  ["f","g","h","i","j"],
                  ["k","l","m","n","o"],
                  ["p","q","r","s","t"],
                  ["u","v","w","x","y"]])
word = str(input("Enter a word"))
wordletters = list(word)
numbers = []
print(wordletters)
print(len(wordletters))
for count in range(0,len(wordletters)):
  solutions = np.argwhere(polybius_square == wordletters[count])
  solutions = solutions.tolist()
*  solutions = [item.replace(3, 10) for item in solutions]*
  print(solutions)
  numbers.append(solutions)
  print(numbers)
print(*numbers, sep=" ")


i tried a couple ways, but none let me get rid of any characters from the items in the lists.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using for index in range(len(list)):. Use for item in list: or for index, item in enumerate(list):

There's also no need to convert word to a list. You can iterate over the characters in string the same way you iterate over a list.

Nor is it necessary to call str on the result of input: it's already a string.

The encryption algorithm isn't really the question.  You have an np.array in this format:
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[4, 3]])
print(arr)

Output:
[[4 3]]

and want the two-digit value:
num = arr[0][0] * 10 + arr[0][1]
print(num)

Output:
43


If you want the output to be made up of strictly 2-digit values (e.g., 04) then you could do this:
import numpy as np

polybius_square = np.array(
    [
        ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
        ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o"],
        ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t"],
        ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y"],
    ]
)

word = "hello" # the input word
numbers = []

for c in word:
    r = np.argwhere(polybius_square == c)
    if len(r) == 1: 
        numbers.append("{}{}".format(*r[0]))

print(*numbers)

Output:
12 04 21 21 24

